# Default value in HTML form (handling roles by views or by default)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am going to describe the need, I hope to make myself understood: I need to use several forms for users, according to the form filled in as a type of user, in my user model I use the id of another table for role management.
in the html try to insert something like this:

`value="9"`

However it does not work, I'm using angular and the backend is developed in .Net Core.

Comment: Please share more core with the question or add stackblitz demo

Comment: @nitin9nair. thanks for answering, in angular step my model composed by:
`{
"user": "",
"password": "",
"role": "",
"address": "",
"phone": ""
}
`
this through the clear endpoint is.

but in the form I only use explicitly four of the five data by means of the html, user, password, address and phone, in the case of role, I want it to have the number "5" but that the user does not interact with it (something like that as a hidden)

Comment: Update all *relevant* code in your question, **not** in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intention-
Why do not you use [Form-group](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup), with form control? 
Where you can enter a default value, like this-

```
fb.group({
   yourControl: [0] // '0' is the default value
});
```

Hope this helps you, and that I understood what you mean.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that. Good luck later!